# Safe Deposit Boxes & Dehumidifiers

Tags: storage, maintenance, slides, print-preservation, humidity

I currently store all my photographic material in my bedroom cupboard. The temperature is around 20 C and the RH is 60%. I have been researching ways to bring this figure down to 50%.

I would like to know if anyone has tried storing their photos and slides in a safe deposit box at home (not rented from a bank) with a dehumidifier inside?

What has your experience been like and is it a storage method you would recommend?

Would you recommend zip-lock bags for added protection?

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I store all of my camera gear in a cabinet (wood with glass doors) with silica packs on each shelf. Avg temp is 20C, average humidity is 75%. I haven't been able to measure the humidity in the cabinet yet so, not sure of the results. (hence, not an answer). Keep your slides dry, cool, and in the dark is the going wisdom though.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by a "safe deposit box at home." Do you mean a small home "safe?". Or the drawer from a safe deposit vault at a bank?

Comment: I am talking about a home safe you would store valuables in.

Comment: @RichardGray I keep my kit in my camera bag or bag they came in, have done so for over a year without noticing an issue - are you expecting something to break if you don't get exactly 50%?

Comment: Hi Matthew,

Not necessarily, I just want to make sure I'm doing all I can to protect my materials.

Comment: @Matthew Bags are notorious for holding moisture, particularly those with foam cushioning inside the fabric walls. It's generally not recommended to leave camera gear stored in leather or fabric bags long term.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about fire, **it is prudent to store flammable materials in a fireproof box.** If you are in an area prone to flooding, you might consider keeping your film and photographs offsite (perhaps in a bank safe deposit box).

It is preferable to use **"archival" quality** storage systems. Zip lock bags are not suitable for this purpose. They can also trap moisture.

Use of a **dehumidifier should be avoided** because they use heat to draw moisture from the air. **Heat can accelerate degradation** of stored materials. However, it is a good idea to **use a desiccant,** such as silica gel packs. To ensure that they continue to work, you should periodically **replace or regenerate** them. You can regenerate them by heating them for a few minutes. Let them cool before reuse.